# Optimizing number of optimum features

Tags: optimization, scikit-learn, neural-network, keras, feature-selection

I am training neural network using Keras. Every time I train my model, I use slightly different set of features selected using `Tree-based feature selection` via `ExtraTreesClassifier()`. After training every time, I compute the `AUCROC` on my validation set and then go back in a loop to train the model again with different set of feature.  This process is very inefficient and I want to select the optimum number of features using some optimization technique available in some python library.
The function to be optimized is the `auroc` for cross validation which can only be calculated after training the model on selected features. The features are selected via following function  `ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators=10, criterion=’gini’, max_depth=None, min_samples_split=2, min_samples_leaf=1, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, max_features=’auto’)` Here we see that the objective function is not directly dependent on the parameters to be optimized. The objective function  which is `auroc` is related to the neural network training and the neural network takes features as input which are extracted on the basis of their important from `ExtraTreesClassifier`. 
So in a way, the parameters for which I optimize `auroc` are `n_estimators=10, criterion=’gini’, max_depth=None, min_samples_split=2, min_samples_leaf=1, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, max_features=’auto’` or some other variables in `ExtraTreesClassifier`. These are not directly related to `auroc`.

Comment: May be I need to use `sklearn pipeline`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should combine GridSearchCV and Pipeline. [Find more here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_compare_reduction.html)
Use Pipeline when you need to run a set of instruction in sequence to get the optimal config.

For example, you have these steps to run:
1. Select KBest feature(s)
2. Use classifier DecisionTree or NaiveBayes

By combining GridSearchCV and Pipeline, you can select which features that best for a particular classifier, best config on the classifier, and so on, based on the scoring criteria.

Example:

```
#set your configuration options 
param_grid = [{
    'classify': [DecisionTreeClassifier()], #first option use DT
    'kbest__k': range(1, 22), #range of n in SelectKBest(n)

    #classifier's specific configs
    'classify__criterion': ('gini', 'entropy'), 
    'classify__min_samples_split': range(2,10),
    'classify__min_samples_leaf': range(1,10)
},
{
    'classify': [GaussianNB()], #second option use NB
    'kbest__k': range(1, 22), #range of n in SelectKBest(n)
}]

pipe =  Pipeline(steps=[("kbest", SelectKBest()), ("classify",  DecisionTreeClassifier())]) #I put DT as default, but eventually the program will ignore this when you use GridSearchCV.

# Here the might of GridSearchCV working, this may takes time especially if you have more than one classifiers to be evaluated
grid = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid=param_grid, cv=10, scoring='f1')
grid.fit(features, labels)

#Find your best params if you want to use optimal setting later without running the grid search again (by commenting all these grid search lines)
print grid.best_params_

#You can now use pipeline again to wrap the steps with it best configs to build your model
pipe =  Pipeline(steps=[("kbest", SelectKBest(k=12)), ("classify",  DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion="entropy", min_samples_leaf=2, min_samples_split=9))])
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I implemented it here with details but I am still confused in applying the pipeline with Grid Search.
 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48730921/optimizing-two-estimators-dependent-on-each-other-using-sklearn-grid-search)

Answer (score 0):

The flow of my program is in two stages.

I am using Sklearn `ExtraTreesClassifier` along with `SelectFromModel`method to select the most important features. Here it should be noted that the `ExtraTreesClassifier` takes many parameters as input  like `n_estimators` etc for classification and eventually giving different set of important features for different values of `n_estimators` via `SelectFromModel`. This means that I can optimize the `n_estimators` to get the best features.

In the second stage, I am traing my NN keras model based on the features selected in the first stage. I am using AUROC as the score for grid search but this AUROC is calculated using Keras based neural network. I want to use Grid Search for `n_estimators` in my `ExtraTreesClassifier` to optimize the AUROC of keras neural Network. I know I have to use Pipline but I am confused in implementing both together.

I don't know where to put Pipeline in my code. I am getting an error which says`TypeError: estimator should be an estimator implementing 'fit' method, <function fs at 0x0000023A12974598> was passed`

```
#################################################################################
I concatenate the CV set and the train set so that I may select the most important features  
in both CV and Train together.
##############################################################################

frames11 = [train_x_upsampled, cross_val_x_upsampled]
train_cv_x = pd.concat(frames11)
frames22 = [train_y_upsampled, cross_val_y_upsampled]
train_cv_y = pd.concat(frames22)


def fs(n_estimators):
  m = ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators = tree_number)
  m.fit(train_cv_x,train_cv_y)
  sel = SelectFromModel(m, prefit=True)


  ##################################################
  The code below is to get the names of the selected important features
  ###################################################

  feature_idx = sel.get_support()
  feature_name = train_cv_x.columns[feature_idx]
  feature_name =pd.DataFrame(feature_name)

  X_new = sel.transform(train_cv_x)
  X_new =pd.DataFrame(X_new)

 ######################################################################
 So Now the important features selected are in the data-frame X_new. In 
 code below, I am again dividing the data into train and CV but this time 
 only with the important features selected.
 #################################################################### 

  train_selected_x = X_new.iloc[0:train_x_upsampled.shape[0], :]
  cv_selected_x = X_new.iloc[train_x_upsampled.shape[0]:train_x_upsampled.shape[0]+cross_val_x_upsampled.shape[0], :]

  train_selected_y = train_cv_y.iloc[0:train_x_upsampled.shape[0], :]
  cv_selected_y = train_cv_y.iloc[train_x_upsampled.shape[0]:train_x_upsampled.shape[0]+cross_val_x_upsampled.shape[0], :]

  train_selected_x=train_selected_x.values
  cv_selected_x=cv_selected_x.values
  train_selected_y=train_selected_y.values
  cv_selected_y=cv_selected_y.values

  ##############################################################
  Now with this new data which only contains the important features,
  I am training a neural network as below.
  #########################################################
  def create_model():
     n_x_new=train_selected_x.shape[1]

     model = Sequential()
     model.add(Dense(n_x_new, input_dim=n_x_new, kernel_initializer='glorot_normal', activation='relu'))
     model.add(Dense(10, kernel_initializer='glorot_normal', activation='relu'))
     model.add(Dropout(0.8))

     model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='glorot_normal', activation='sigmoid'))
     optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)


     model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])

  seed = 7
  np.random.seed(seed)

model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, epochs=20, batch_size=400, verbose=0)

n_estimators=[10,20,30]
param_grid = dict(n_estimators=n_estimators)

grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=fs, param_grid=param_grid,scoring='roc_auc',cv = PredefinedSplit(test_fold=my_test_fold), n_jobs=1)
grid_result = grid.fit(np.concatenate((train_selected_x, cv_selected_x), axis=0), np.concatenate((train_selected_y, cv_selected_y), axis=0))
```